# Maya polySoftEdge

Tags: attributes, maya

I am writing a mesh exporter plugin for Maya.

I am struggling to get the default polySoftEdge input value for a particular kMesh node. Maya ships with a default of 30.0, but I suspect this can be changed so am treating it as an unknown.

So the problem is the polySoftEdge input node doesn't appear as an input value on the mesh until you select the mesh in the viewer, then in the top menu bar click "normals -> set normal angle" and finally apply a new angle value and the polySoftEdge1 node should appear in the inputs of the selected mesh.

At this point I can get the value by using MEL from my plugin:

float $val = `polySoftEdge -query -angle polySoftEdge1`;

looking at this link:

http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Nodes/polySoftEdge-html.html#attrangle

The attribute is available directly to the API ( rather than having to go through MEL ) but I have no idea how to access it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only query polySoftEdge if such a node exists. Otherwise maya doesn't store smoothing, as Maya defines smoothing as a edge property (thats what the poly soft edge does sets edge values, but these may change later in the computation chain). So maya may or may not use smoothing angles.

Comment: Use OpenMaya to call API functions. [`import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya`](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html?url=files/GUID-856DDB26-93E7-493D-A1D4-60C4CBA38B9C.htm,topicNumber=d30e4461)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query for a polySoftEdge node using the API, you can use an MItDependencyGraph iterator object with the shape node as the root and the filter set to kPolySoftEdge.

Here is a snippet written in the Python flavour of the API to print the polySoftEdge of the selected object(s):

```py
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya

selectionList = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
OpenMaya.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList( selectionList )
selectionIter = OpenMaya.MItSelectionList( selectionList )

dnNodeFn = OpenMaya.MFnDependencyNode()
dagNodeFn = OpenMaya.MFnDependencyNode()
dnGraphNodeFn = OpenMaya.MFnDependencyNode()

while not selectionIter.isDone():
    dnObject = OpenMaya.MObject()
    selectionIter.getDependNode( dnObject )
    dnNodeFn.setObject( dnObject )

    dagIter = OpenMaya.MItDag()
    dagIter.reset( dnObject )

    while not dagIter.isDone():
        dagObject = OpenMaya.MObject() 
        dagObject = dagIter.currentItem()

        if dagObject:
            dagNodeFn.setObject( dagObject )            

            if dagObject.apiType() == OpenMaya.MFn.kMesh:
                dnGraphIter = OpenMaya.MItDependencyGraph(dagObject,
                                                          OpenMaya.MFn.kPolySoftEdge,
                                                          OpenMaya.MItDependencyGraph.kDownstream)

                while not dnGraphIter.isDone():
                    dnGraphNodeFn.setObject( dnGraphIter.currentItem() )
                    print "shape: %s" % ( dagNodeFn.name() )
                    print "polySoftEdge-node-name: %s" % ( dnGraphNodeFn.name() )
                    print "value: %f" % ( dnGraphNodeFn.findPlug("angle").asMAngle().asDegrees() )
                    dnGraphIter.next()

        dagIter.next()

    selectionIter.next()
```

Sample output:

```
shape: pSphereShape1
polySoftEdge-node-name: polySoftEdge1
value: 180.000000
```

Comment: I was able to do this from within the Maya Api using the kPolySoftEdge. It seems to be a global setting that is queried through the object dependancy graph this is why I was confused. Thanks.

Comment: Which global setting do you mean? The pokySoftEdge is a node that needs to be added to the mesh. It is not global and is not an integral part of the mesh, as joojaa suggested.

Comment: In the Maya application I selected Normals->"Set Normal Angle" from the main tab. Echo'ing the value to the script editor as I changed it allowed me to find the Maya variable which stored the normal angle value. Hope that clarifies how I resolved this.